# Asana/php-asana getTasks() Invalid Request Error

Tags: php, laravel-7, asana, asana-api, asana-connect

Whenever I use `getTasks()` it returns `Invalid Request`

However when I use `getTasksForProject` it will return values.

**getTasks()**

```
$tasks = $asana_client->tasks->getTasks(["opt_fields" => "name,due_on"]);

foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    var_dump($task);//will return error
}
```

**getTasksForProject**

```
$tasks = $asana_client->tasks->getTasksForProject($projects[12]->gid, ["opt_fields" => "name,due_on"]);

foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    var_dump($task);    
}
```

`object(stdClass)#312 (3) { ["gid"]=> string(16) "**8**3*31**73173" ["due_on"]=> string(10) "2020-06-26" ["name"]=> string(15) "Navbar Settings" }`

What causes this error, under the documentation it does not say that a parameter for projectid is needed?

Answer (score 0):

i try your code for project and works but the task script has a problem, i solved it like this:

my tasks function by workspace and asiggnee user gid:

```
public function getTasks($gid,$workspace,$client)
    {
        $tasks = $client->tasks->getTasks(array('workspace' => $workspace, 'assignee' => $gid), ["opt_fields" => "assignee,name,completed,start_on,due_on,completed_at,created_at,notes,parent,num_subtasks"]);
        return  $tasks;
    }
```

and i called like this:

```
$tasks=collect($this->getTasks($user->gid,$workspace[0]->gid,$asana_client))->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

Finally try the items retrieved like this: `return dd($tasks);`

PD: sorry by my bad endglish